# Phpstorm 10, laravel 5.1.11 method not found

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel-5.1

Im going insane with Laravel 5.1.11 and PHPStorm 10, My problem is that im getting the infamous 'Method Not Found error'.

I have installed both: The Laravel Plugin and the IDE Helper from Barry.  Also yes: The plugin is enabled.

I have also run: 
    "php artisan clear-compiled", 
    "php artisan ide-helper:generate", 
    "php artisan optimize"

What the problem is:

For example: inside my resource controller, Customer::find($id); It get the method "find" not found warning, If I go to the Costumer Class and extend it to Eloquent that problem goes away, but the methods that I personally created for the class get me the method not found warning in the IDE.

Any ideas?

This is my customer class:

```
namespace App\Models\Customer;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;



class Customer extends \Eloquent {

use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'customers';

public function Quotes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Quotes\Quotes');
}

public function Invoices(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Invoices\Invoices');
}

public function Comprobante() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Comprobantes\CompCustomer', 'customer_id');
}

public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function Calc_Invoice(){
    $invoices = $this->Invoices()->get();

    $total = 0;
    foreach($invoices as $key){
        $total = $total + $key->total;
    }
    return $total;
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your `Customer` class. You **have** to extend Eloquent for stuff like `find()` to work, as they're provided by Eloquent.

Comment: @ceejayoz there is the class, for example `$customer->Comprobante()->get();` gives me `Method 'Comprobante' not found in class \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null`

Comment: Try lowercasing `Comprobante` in both the class and where you call it. Laravel relationships are case-sensitive despite PHP's not being. Also, you don't need `->get()` - you can do `$customer->comprobante` and it'll do the `->get()` for you behind the scenes. Makes for nicer code.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but i dont see why the case should matter when im using the correct case both times, anyway, i tried and it didnt work.  I think that problem is that PHPStorm is looking for the method ONLY in the class `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|nul‌​l` and not also in the Customer class.